# How to access the servicestack request object

Tags: c#, web-services, servicestack

I have created a web service using ServiceStacks ServiceStack with Razor template. This service could be hosted in one of many locations. I want to be able to determine information about the uri of a given service. Here is my code -

```
    [Route("/Test")]
    public class Test : IReturn <TestResponse> {}

    public class TestResponse
        {
            public string something;
        }

    public class TestService : Service
        {
            public object Any(Test request)
                {
                    return new TestResponse() { something = base.Request.AbsoluteUri};
                }
        }
```

Whether I call this from a test or from typing it into my browser, base.Request always shows as null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

base.Request isn't null, the issue is due to `something` being a public field instead of a **public property**.

Comment: All I can say is DOH!